# Why gcc complains "declaration of 'foo' shadows a previous call [-Werror=shadow]"

Tags: c++, gcc

I have this MCVE:

```
auto bar() -> double { return 8.0; }

int main()
{
    if ( auto foo = bar() )
    {
        return foo;
    }
    else if ( auto foo = bar() )
    {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Compiling it with `gcc 7.3` and these options `-c -Werror -Wextra -Wall -Wshadow` generates these error messages:

```
test-shadow.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test-shadow.cpp:9:17: error: declaration of ‘foo’ shadows a previous local [-Werror=shadow]
  else if ( auto foo = bar() )
                 ^~~
test-shadow.cpp:5:12: note: shadowed declaration is here
  if ( auto foo = bar() )
```

I don't understand why the 2nd `foo` is *shadowing* the 1st definition.

**My question:**

Why is `gcc` generating this error? In my eyes the scope of the 1st `foo` definition is valid only within the `if` block and therefore the 2nd definition is not *shadowing* the 1st.

Comment: Note that `foo` isn't declared within a `{ block scope }`.  It is declared within your if-statement.  Where does your first if-statement end?

Comment: The scope of something declared in a condition is until the end of the substatements that are controlled by that condition.

Comment: In other words: `if (auto foo=...)` -- foo is declared for the scope of the ***entire*** `if` statement, including the `else` part. And your `else` part declares another `foo`. Hence the shadowing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's basically like this:

```
auto bar() -> double { return 8.0; }

int main()
{
    { // start of if scope
        auto foo = bar();
        if (foo)
        {
            return foo;
        }
        else
        {
            auto foo = bar(); // this foo shadows previous foo
            if (foo)
            {
                return foo;
            }
        }
    } // end of if scope
}
```

Hope the code explains it :)